# Return SUM value of same members from two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables; one stores users, one stores expenses on each user and third table returns of each user. Each is connected by the user. But there are are many users who don't use the service so I would love to avoid a solution that wouldn't scan entire users table.

I am using MySQL btw.

```
users: id, name
expenses: id,userid,amount,date
returns:id,userid,amount
```

Sample data would be:

```
users:
 1             Sosuna
 2             Mike

expenses:

 1 1  100 2017-01-01
 2 1   20 2017-01-13
 3 2   50 2017-02-13

returns:

 1  1  20
 2  1  10
 3  1  30
 4  1  10
```

Now the expected output is simply a combo of them. A user cant exist in returns without ever existing in expenses, tho.

```
 user_id       name      total_expenses        total_returns
   1          Sosuna       120                    70
   2           Mike         50                     0
```

I have tried several queries but none works. This UNION ALL query works but the output is not what is desired. I wish to have hte output without having to use any front end stuff:

```
    SELECT SUM(amount) as total_given,userid,'expense' as source FROM `expenses` GROUP BY userid,source
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SUM(amount) as total_returned,userid,'returnedback' as source FROM returns GROUP BY userid,source ORDER BY userid,source
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
select id, max(name) as name, sum(expenses) as expenses, sum(returns) as returns
from ((select id, name, 0 as expenses, 0 as returns
       from users
      ) union all
      (select userid, null, amount, 0
       from expenses
      ) union all
      (select userid, null, 0, amount
       from returns
      )
     ) uer
 group by id;
```

EDIT:

An alternative method would be:

```
select u.*,
       (select sum(e.amount) from expenses e where e.userid = u.id
       ) as expenses,
       (select sum(r.amount) from returns r where r.userid = u.id
       ) as returns
from users;
```

This will be faster if you have indexes on `expenses(userid, amount)` and `returns(userid, amount)`.

Comment: it does work but it appears slower than I wanted it. I have nearly 300k users.